# Using JWT with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm trying to add JWT instead of express-session in the backend.
I can't figure out how to use it with nodejs + routes.

I tried this, so i will be able to use it in every route:

```
const jwt = 'jsonwebtoken'
app.use(jwt())
```

and I got that "jwt is not a function".

than I tried this:

```
app.use(
  jwt.sign({}, 'secret')
);
```

and i got that "app.use() requires a middleware function"
and instead of the {} I would like to enter the user when the frontend will pass one.

should I create jwtService file and import it to every route that use jwt?
or require jsonwebtoken in each route?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install the package, and you need to import/require it first.

```
const jwt =require('jsonwebtoken');
```

Comment: i did it, but i have routes in my app, jwt doesn’t work in the other routes. i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined" in other routes.. should i require jwt in every file at the backend that use it? ... or i can use app.use(jwt) like i do with session?

Comment: Yes, you need to import in every file that needs jwt directly.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can implement these libraries will always vary according to your project standard.

I will try to simplify a little bit here to make as much easier as I can.

Let's suppose you have a `/login` route.

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post('/login', loginHandler); // YOUR route with JWT inside of login funciton.

app.listen(3000);
```

The second parameter of the `app.post` will be the function that has your JWT handlers in it, like:

```js
const loginHandler = (req, res) => {
  // username and password
  const { username, password } = req.body

  // create new token
  const myJwtToken = jwt.sign({ username }, 
   jwtKey, {
    algorithm: 'HS256',
    expiresIn: XXSeconds // The expiredIn property can be human readable like '6 months', '1 week', etc.
  });

  console.log('My token is: ', myJwtToken);

  // set token and expiry date
  res.cookie('token', myJwtToken, { maxAge: XXSeconds * 1000 });
  res.end();
}
```

**Useful links:**

- [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) with examples
- Example implementation I [Node.js with JWT](https://dev.to/_marcba/secure-your-node-js-application-with-json-web-token-4d4e) - DEVTO
- Example implementation II - [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52/)